# Fastest most elegant way to split websocket buffer into different variables so that they can be compared

Tags: websocket

Best way to send & receive an array over websockets

On the client side I'm using javascript that sends the data.

I'm sending to a microcontroller ([ESP8266](https://www.adafruit.com/images/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf)) that is programmed in c++ using the [websocket](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) library with the arduino IDE

At the moment I'm sending the variable which I build up on the client side.
It is then sent to the microcontroller and received by the payload buffer.

I am sending this from the client

```
#,tank,pond,1537272000,1537272000,Normal,4789,12
```

I received here in the code:

```
case WStype_TEXT: Serial.printf("[%u] get Text: %s\n", num, payload);
this is the result of what I receive
[0] here it is: #,tank,pond,1537272000,1537272000,Normal,4789,12
```

I am using a hash(#) to mark the start of the data.
I have been googling and searching forums for days but can't fathom which is the best way to do this.
What is the fastest most elegant code to split this up into different variables so that they can be compared?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, I prefer JSON. You can use the library below for ESP8266:

https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson

I think your websocket server is written in a high level language so neither JSON parsing nor composing will not be an issue for you.

Good luck.